# Получить значения из структуры json

Tags: golang

Полученные данные, структура которых json, вношу в переменную s.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var s = `{
        "abc": {
               "a": {
                    "x": {"p": "val"},
                    "y": {"p": "msg", "b": 33.5, "ms": 0},
                    "z": {"p": "msg ", "b": -12, "ms": 0}
               },
               "b": ["x", "y", "z"],
               "c": [
                    [69, "text_05", "m n o"],
                    [4, " text_02", "def"],
                    [1, "text_01", "abc "],
                    [48, " text_04 ", "jkl"],
                    [5, " text_03 ", " ghi"],
                    [82, "text_06  ", " pq r "]
                    ]
               },
        "xyz": {
               "z": [
                    [11, "aaa"],
                    [33, "bbb"]
                    ]
}}`

func main() {
    var f map[string]interface{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &f); err != nil {

        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    d := []string{}
    for key := range f {
        d = append(d, key)
    }

    fmt.Println(len(d)) //  2
    fmt.Println(d)      //  [abc xyz]

    for j := 0; j < len(d); j++ {

        // ...
    }
}
```

Как получить все ключи и значения данной структуры. Получил ключи *abc* и *xyz*. Как пройтись по ключам: *a, x, y, z, p, b, c* и их значениям?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша задача решается рекурсивным обходом по мапам и массивам.

```
func GetMapKeysRecursive(m map[string]any) []string {
    result := []string{}
    for k, v := range m {
        result = append(result, k)
        result = append(result, GetKeysRecursive(v)...)
    }
    return result
}

func GetArrayKeysRecursive(a []any) []string {
    result := []string{}
    for _, v := range a {
        result = append(result, GetKeysRecursive(v)...)
    }
    return result
}

func GetKeysRecursive(a any) []string {
    switch a.(type) {
    case map[string]any:
        return GetMapKeysRecursive(a.(map[string]any))
    case []any:
        return GetArrayKeysRecursive(a.([]any))
    default:
        return []string{}
    }
}
```

Полный пример здесь: https://go.dev/play/p/B002DHUb7WF

Обратите внимание, в нём я немного изменил ваш json, поменял в массиве `xyz.z` один объект, чтобы показать что обходчик заходит внутрь массивов.

Также обратите внимание, что порядок выдачи ключей отличается от порядка ключей в документе json, так как мапы в golang неупорядочены.

Answer (score 1):

```
abc_a := f["abc"].(map[string]interface{})["a"]
fmt.Println(abc_a)

abc_a_z := abc_a.(map[string]interface{})["z"]
fmt.Println(abc_a_z)
```

Comment: возможно не уловил Вашу мысль, но ключи не известны, .т.е, например, ключи: ["abc"] ["a"] ["x"] ["p"] надо ещё получить, чтобы по ним получить значения и так далее .. чтобы охватить ключи и значения всей приведенной структуры .. в цикле .. , так делаю https://go.dev/play/p/_oVXLQt3zHu , но что-то криво и без охвата всего в цикле. Спасибо.

Comment: проще говоря нужно добраться до всех конечных значений (элементов массивов и других) по ключам, которые не известны, но сама структура данных постоянна. и очень важна скорость.